# Batch entries by year?

Tags: loop

I have a press release index page that loops through all the press releases. I want to organize them by year. So everything in 2018 will have a header that says 2018 press releases and then all the press releases for 2018 and so on.

Should I do a conditional that checks the date, or is there something like the | batch but for date? Open to ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [group](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/filters.html#group) filter

```twig
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').all() %}

{% set allEntriesByYear = allEntries|group('postDate.year') %}

{% for year, entriesInYear in allEntriesByYear %}
    <h2>{{ year }}</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entriesInYear %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```